# Parameter is Invalid when retrieving Image from a stream

Tags: vb.net

I need to get an image from a stream. On first run, I am able to get the image and save it but on the second time, I get the error of "Parameter is Invalid"
Please see my code below:

```
Dim url = "http://172.23.111.102//onvifsnapshot/media_service/snapshot?channel=1&subtype=1"
Dim req As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)

Private Sub LaneCtl_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    req.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("admin", "admin")
End Sub

Private Function CaptureImage(ByVal imagePath As String, ByVal fileName As String, CaptureNow As Boolean) As String
    Try
        If CaptureNow Then
            If (CamType = 2) Then

                Dim fn = fileName
                Dim filePath = imagePath
                Dim file = $"{filePath}{fn}"

                Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(99999) {}
                Dim read As Integer = 0
                Dim total As Integer = 0

                Dim resp As WebResponse = req.GetResponse
                Dim stream As IO.Stream = resp.GetResponseStream
                Dim bm As Image = New Bitmap(stream)
                bm.Save(file, Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
            End If

        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        CreateLogTextFile(String.Format("Error on Capture Image Request >> {0}", ex.Message.ToString), False)
    End Try
    Return IO.Path.Combine(imagePath, fileName)
End Function
```

I need your help please. Thank you.

Comment: I need it for recording.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 Dim bm As Image = Image.FromStream (stream)
 bm.Save(file, Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
 bm.Dispose ()
```

Comment: Still a no go. Weird though, if I place the global variables inside the method, I get the image.

Comment: Are you sure some other part of your code is not modifying the value of those variables?

Comment: Yes. This is being called on one method only.

Comment: Which global variables are you talking about exactly? url?

Comment: The url and req variables Sir

Comment: leave those variables outside and in the function add this to the first line `req =DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)`

Comment: Thank you for the help Sir.